# How can I Route on version numbers that contain dots in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, routes

I have a path that will sometime contain dots.  For example:

```
https://website.com/user/tom/version/1.0.0  // doesn't route
https://website.com/user/tom/version/5 // routes properly
https://website.com/user/bob/version/6.7.8/run/15 //routes properly
```

My React Router code looks like this:

```
<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/user/:user/version/:version" element={<MainContainer/>} />
        <Route path="/user/:user/version/:version/run/:runNumber" element={<MainContainer/>} />>
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

How can I make it so that a version with dots properly routes on the `/user/:user/version/:version` path?